# How to share an implementation of the interface using prism?

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism, prism-5

Based on MSDN,if you registered an existing instance of an object using the `RegisterInstance` method, the container returns the same instance for all calls to Resolve or ResolveAll or when the dependency mechanism injects instances into other classes.

I create a project for `dataService` layer and used

```
container.RegisterInstance<IQuoteSource>(new IBQuoteSource());
```

I expect whenever I need `IQuoteSource`, only one instance is created during the lifetime of the application.
But in another project assembly when I use the interface in the constructor, what happend is another `IBQuoteSource` is created.(As I can see the constructor of `IBQuoteSource` is called again) So how to share one implementation of the interface across the application?

```
public ClickViewModel( IQuoteSource quoteSource)
{
    this.quoteSource = quoteSource;
    ComboItems = new List<string>() { "GTC Order", "Day Order" };
    SelectedComBoItem = ComboItems[1];
}
```

Comment: How do you register your injection constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misinterpeted the doco - using RegisterInstance means that the same *implementation* of the registered interface will be returned, not the same *concrete instance*.

To get what you want, you need to use a [ContainerControlledLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

```
container.RegisterInstance<IQuoteSource>( new IBQuoteSource()
                                        , new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()
                                        );
```

(note: untested line of code!)
This will effectively use the singleton pattern with your container - the initial instance created is used every time that interface is resolved.

Also, just to nitpick - I would suggest you change the name of `IBQuoteSource` - it's an actual class, not an interface so ideally it shouldn't have a capital `I` prepended on the front of the class name.

Comment: Are you sure about `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager `, as I think this is the default implementation. And `IB` is short for Interactive Broker~